# Auto-incrementing a column name when searching for a string

Tags: python, pandas

I need to search for certain strings within a selection of columns in a dataset, around 50 different strings in total.
The columns all following a naming pattern of name1, name2, name3 etc up to 40.

Currently I'm having to put large blocks of repetitive code which I'm sure can't be right. Example below:

```
criteria = (df.name2.str.contains("String001", na=False) | df.name3.str.contains("String001", na=False) |
df.name4.str.contains("String001", na=False) | df.name5.str.contains("String001", na=False) |
df.name6.str.contains("String001", na=False) | df.name7.str.contains("String001", na=False) |
df.name8.str.contains("String001", na=False) | df.name9.str.contains("String001", na=False) | 
df.name10.str.contains("String001", na=False) | df.name11.str.contains("String001", na=False) |
df.name12.str.contains("String001", na=False) | df.name13.str.contains("String001", na=False) |
df.name14.str.contains("String001", na=False) | df.name15.str.contains("String001", na=False) | 
df.name16.str.contains("String001", na=False) | df.name17.str.contains("String001", na=False) | 
df.name18.str.contains("String001", na=False) | df.name19.str.contains("String001", na=False) |
df.name20.str.contains("String001", na=False) | df.name21.str.contains("String001", na=False) |
df.name22.str.contains("String001", na=False) | df.name23.str.contains("String001", na=False) |
df.name24.str.contains("String001", na=False) | df.name25.str.contains("String001", na=False) |
df.name26.str.contains("String001", na=False) | df.name27.str.contains("String001", na=False) |
df.name28.str.contains("String001", na=False) | df.name29.str.contains("String001", na=False) |
df.name30.str.contains("String001", na=False) | df.name31.str.contains("String001", na=False) |
df.name32.str.contains("String001", na=False) | df.name33.str.contains("String001", na=False) |
df.name34.str.contains("String001", na=False) | df.name35.str.contains("String001", na=False) |
df.name36.str.contains("String001", na=False) | df.name37.str.contains("String001", na=False) |
df.name38.str.contains("String001", na=False) | df.name39.str.contains("String001", na=False) |
df.name40.str.contains("String001", na=False))
```

I'm sure this can be done with a For loop but I cannot work out how to make it work.

Comment: `df["name" + str(2)]` instead of `df.name2` - and now you can use some loop to make it shorter.

Comment: f strings are the preferred way to do dynamic string manipulation in python these days like `f"name{k}" for k in range(0,10)`. [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
import functools
criteria = functools.reduce(lambda a,b: a|b, [df[f"name{i}"].str.contains("String001", na=False) for i in range(2,41)])
```

Answer (score 0):

If i'm reading your code correctly you want it to return true if `String001` is in any of the given columns. You can use an f string to parameterize your column names so you can loop through them with a list comprehension. From there you can then use the pandas `any()` to reduce the series mask to a true/false value if the string is in the column and then just convert it to a `Series`

```
criteria = pd.Series([df[f"name{i}"].str.contains("String001", na=False).any() for i in range(2, 41)])
```

Here's the code ran:

```
>>> d = {'name2': ['1', 'String001'], 'name3': ['3','4']}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(d)
>>> criteria = pd.Series([df[f"name{i}"].str.contains("String001", na=False).any() for i in range(2, 4)])
>>> criteria
0     True
1    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thank you!
I like that I don't need another module for this solution.
I actually want to keep the mask, as I'm applying it to a few different sub-sets.
I tried:

```criteria = [df[f"name{i}"].str.contains("String001", na=False) for i in range(2, 4)])```
but this didn't quite seem to work either.

Comment: @Natrilix what do you mean keep the mask? Can you detail what you would like the output to be in the question?